# Running cron on Cygwin to call notifu

Tags: windows, cron, cygwin

I have installed Cygwin with `cygrunsrv` and Cron so I could use the benefits of using Linux-style scheduling in Windows. I want to call [notifu](http://www.paralint.com/projects/notifu/) from a cron job.

I Installed cron as a service using the command:

```
cygrunsrv -I cron -d "CYGWIN cron" -u cron_srv -p /usr/sbin/cron -a -n
```

Everything is ok, the service is running and not reporting any errors. Also I gave this `cron_srv` user all privileges it needs, so it can switch user contexts etc.

`crontab -l` gives these two jobs I have defined:

```
HOME=/home/<username>
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/cygdrive/c/utils/notifu:$PATH
# testing
* * * * * echo "Cron test at $(date +\%k:\%M)" >> ~/testcron.txt 2>&1
* * * * * notifu /p "Balloon Title" /t warn /w /m "event description"
```

`cronevents` gives this:

```
2014/03/03 13:08:01 [cron_srv] /usr/sbin/cron: PID 2592: (branchito) CMD (echo "Cron test at $(date +%k:%M)" >> ~/testcron.txt 2>&1)
2014/03/03 13:08:01 [cron_srv] /usr/sbin/cron: PID 4076: (branchito) CMD (notifu /p "Balloon Title" /t warn /w /m "event description")
```

..so no errors. And I have my `testcron.txt` file created, and populated correctly with my custom date test. But `notifu` does not pop up a balloon with message, although it does not report any error in `cronevents`, and appears to be executed just as well as his friend date test job.

I set my `PATH` variable explicitly so it can find the `notifu` program, even though it is contained in the last appended `PATH`, but I wanted to be sure.

The interesting part is that the `notifu` command runs without any problem from Cygwin terminal, balloon is popping with message all well, but from thecron job it is not trigerring.

I read something about the `DISPLAY` environment variable, could that be a problem maybe? If so, how would I set its value in the crontab file? On Linux it is like `DISPLAY=:0.0`, but I don't know how to set this value on Windows.

**EDIT**

Doing some more research, I came to know that the problem lies in the fact that as of Windows Vista, services act only and only in `session 0 isolation` level, so they cannot interact with Desktop as a security precaution, or they can but in some special way of secure desktop instance.

I would like someone to tell me how it would be possible in this case (my case), for this service to be able to send message to that `notifu` app, justo to popup balloon tip with that message, and would that be possible without modifing service itself, because I am not the author of it. So is there any way I could give that service some `logon as` permissions, so it would act in userspace.

Comment: Notifu doesn't use X11, so `DISPLAY` doesn't apply. It's a native Windows application, not part of Cygwin. The problem may be related to the way cron is a service running in a different context from the user session. As this question is highly likely to require Windows expertise, it would be better off on [su]. The relevance to [unix.se] is at best marginal. I've flagged for migration to [su], please do not repost.

Comment: What Windows version, please? I think I have a method that could help you, but it differs between XP and 7.

Comment: it is windows 7, thank you. because windows xp does not have that problem, session 0 isolation was first introduced in windows vista.

Comment: Excuse me for the delay, @branquito. I hope to face this problem as soon as possible, but I think I will last some days, so here is the link to the possible (probable?) solution to your question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4284420/1461017 . It is not an easy to do thing, but I think it will work. When I will have some more concrete results about it, I will post them here, of course.